# Focused Window Indicators

Tags: 18.04, gnome, indicator, dash-to-dock

I know this looks like Pop!OS, but it is, in fact, Ubuntu.  It has themes and extensions installed.  I was just wondering if it was possible to remove the little white current window indicator in the dock.  If you look at the picture, then you can see above the settings icon, the wee little dot there.  I have looked in Dash to Dock settings, and it does not have an option to disable this.  I am on GNOME Shell 3.28.4.[image]
How do I get rid of this?  Again, I am on GNOME Shell 3.28.4, running Ubuntu 18.04.
Thank you.

Comment: What are the outputs of `gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name` and `gsettings list-recursively | grep enabled-extensions`

Comment: it appears to be with the gnome-shell theme that is you are using.. if you observe the image you attached.. the settings icon is the running app and focused.. it has two dots top and bottom.. where as other running apps but not focused, have dots only at bottom.. unless you provide your shell-theme, we cant dig.. but in my trail this is the case.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVsyS.png

Comment: your shell theme might be using the icon in the attached pic.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDnXt.png if you provide the link to your shell-theme.. I could try.. Thanks!!!

Comment: Oh my gosh... If I weren't such a dingus, I would've thought to look in the theme files.  had no idea that it could've been the theme.  Anyways, I looked and there it was... just in plain sight.  Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but it was in plain sight in the theme files.  all i need to do is delete the file with the indicator dot.  Silly me.